# How to make (No Internet Connection) broadCastReceiver accessible to all the activities

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm using ConnectivityManager for checking Internet Connection, the problem is, I can't restart the activity when internet is enabled and I can't show the error message(no internet connection) from all the activities.Below is my code

```
  ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(!(networkInfo!=null && networkInfo.isConnected())){
      Intent i = new Intent(this,NoInternetConnection.class);
      startActivity(i);
    }
```

For NoInternetConnection class, I coded like below

```
 public class NoInternetConnection extends AppCompatActivity {
private static ImageView internetStatus;
private static TextView noConnectionText;
private static Button tryAgain;
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final ActionBar actionBar =getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_no_internet_connection);
    internetStatus = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.internetStatus);
    noConnectionText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.noConnectionText);
    tryAgain=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tryAgain);
    tryAgain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //checking internet connection
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (!(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())) 
            {
              onRestart();
            }
            else {
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
    internetStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
    noConnectionText.setText("No Internet Connection");
 }
}
```

Comment: it's still not clear what you want to do. do you want to detect when the user disable connectivity or what? can you edit your post and give more info about this?

Comment: so you want to put on all activity no internet connect depend on internet status but want to use same code ?

Comment: Create a `BaseActivity` and extends all Activity from `BaseActivity`. Do the Connection related task in `BaseActivity`.

Comment: @Ashish yes bro, I need to show(No internet Connection) from all the activities when there is no internet connection and I should fetch data from Server when there is Internet Connection

Comment: @MasterFathi, Sorry to say.. my code is working only for one activity for Showing internet status.. But I don't know, how to make it accessible to all the activites to show9Error message)

Comment: i have one setup of my file where i used and call this code

Comment: @ADM Can you please explain me clearly, how to get it.. If you can, please share the link

Comment: @Ashish Can you please, share that file or tell me what to do with my code(to make accessible to all the activities)

Comment: its in kotlin so you need to workout somehow i can share that but people wont accept it i think

Comment: @Ashish send me bro, I will check it out.

Comment: Let me make for you

Comment: @Ashish I'm waiting, thanks in advance..my mail id is manju.app.developer@gmail.com

Comment: @Manjunath i use this on Kotlin Android development it helps me alot for retrofit calls and other

Comment: @Manjunath I am extremely Sorry i dont have code for java

Comment: okay bro, thanks for your valuable time(for replying)

Comment: if you're still looking for a solution tell me i'll give you a code sample.

Comment: @Master Fathi, yes I'm still looking for the solution, please send me the sample code to manju.app.developer@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create this class

```
public class Utils{

public static void startActivity(Context context,Class clas,Bundle extras)
    {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = 
        (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(!(networkInfo!=null && networkInfo.isConnected())){
            Intent i = new Intent(context,NoInternetConnection.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }else {
            Intent i = new Intent(context,clas);
            i.putExtras(extras);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

and whenever you need to start an activity instead of calling

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,YourActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

call `Utils.startActivity(context,YourActivity.class,new Bundle());`